# Error: Failed to get Firebase project build. Please make sure the project exists and your account has permission to access it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

package json:

```js
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build:dev": "CI=false env-cmd -f .env.local npm run build  && firebase deploy -P build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

when running npm run build:dev returns:

Error: Failed to get Firebase project build. Please make sure the project exists and your account has permission to access it.

firebase-debug.log:

```js
[debug] [2022-01-29T23:34:29.653Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"date":"Sat, 29 Jan 2022 23:34:29 GMT","pragma":"no-cache","expires":"Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT","cache-control":"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","server":"scaffolding on HTTPServer2","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[debug] [2022-01-29T23:34:29.700Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/build [none]
[debug] [2022-01-29T23:34:29.967Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/build 403
[debug] [2022-01-29T23:34:29.967Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/build {"error":{"code":403,"message":"The caller does not have permission","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}
[debug] [2022-01-29T23:34:29.967Z] HTTP Error: 403, The caller does not have permission
[debug] [2022-01-29T23:34:30.049Z] FirebaseError: HTTP Error: 403, The caller does not have permission
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/responseToError.js:38:12)
    at Client.doRequest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/apiv2.js:241:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Client.request (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/apiv2.js:96:20)
    at async getFirebaseProject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/management/projects.js:290:21)
    at async getDefaultHostingSite (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/getDefaultHostingSite.js:8:21)
    at async requireHostingSite (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/requireHostingSite.js:9:18)
    at async Object.fn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/commands/deploy.js:73:9)
    at async /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/command.js:188:17
[error] 
[error] Error: Failed to get Firebase project build. Please make sure the project exists and your account has permission to access it.
```

GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/build errors inside debug:

```js
{
error: {
code: 401,
message: "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
status: "UNAUTHENTICATED",
details: [
{
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
reason: "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
domain: "googleapis.com",
metadata: {
method: "google.firebase.service.v1beta1.FirebaseProjectService.GetFirebaseProject",
service: "firebase.googleapis.com"
}
}
]
}
}
```

I have tried:

- firebase login / logout
- firebase use --add
- firebase login --reauth

still shows the same error; what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change fb alias in cli to project name + change

```js
    "build:dev": "CI=false env-cmd -f .env.local npm run build  && firebase deploy -P riplir",
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to run `firebase use <insert project alias>`. After running that, everything worked perfectly.

Comment: This solved my problem,
although Im in the correct project-id after firebase logout / login, 
but still need running firebase use <project-id> only resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

## Run this

Try `firebase login --reauth`